# How can I access existing map object by dom element?

Tags: jquery, openlayers

Is there any method to acces an existing openlayers map object, using dom?

e.g: 
$("#map_div").data("openLayers") is not working..

Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the OpenLayers.Map instance using the DOM. You need to keep that reference stored in a variable.